# DGraph: Getting JSON Syntax Exception while retrieving Linked data

Tags: java, json, dgraph

I am a newbie to `DGraph`. So, I was experimenting with `dgraph4j` samples and modified it a little.

In the example I am trying to query on following data:

```
{
   "all":[
      {
         "name":"Alice",
         "friend":{
            "name":"Bob"
         }
      },
      {
         "name":"Bob"
      }
   ]
}
```

But as soon as I ran the following program:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;
import io.dgraph.DgraphClient;
import io.dgraph.DgraphClient.Transaction;
import io.dgraph.DgraphGrpc;
import io.dgraph.DgraphGrpc.DgraphBlockingStub;
import io.dgraph.DgraphProto.Mutation;
import io.dgraph.DgraphProto.Operation;
import io.dgraph.DgraphProto.Response;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannel;
import io.grpc.ManagedChannelBuilder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class AppLink {
    private static final String TEST_HOSTNAME = "localhost";
    private static final int TEST_PORT = 9080;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        ManagedChannel channel =
                ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress(TEST_HOSTNAME, TEST_PORT).usePlaintext(true).build();
        DgraphBlockingStub blockingStub = DgraphGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);
        DgraphClient dgraphClient = new DgraphClient(Collections.singletonList(blockingStub));

        // Initialize
        dgraphClient.alter(Operation.newBuilder().setDropAll(true).build());

        // Set schema
        String schema = "name: string @index(exact) .";
        Operation op = Operation.newBuilder().setSchema(schema).build();
        dgraphClient.alter(op);

        Gson gson = new Gson(); // For JSON encode/decode

        Transaction txn = dgraphClient.newTransaction();
        try {
            // Create data
            Person p1 = new Person();
            p1.name = "Alice";
            Person p2 = new Person();
            p2.name = "Bob";
            p1.friend = p2;

            People ppl = new People();
            ppl.all = new ArrayList<>();
            ppl.all.add(p1);
            ppl.all.add(p2);

            // Serialize it
            String json = gson.toJson(ppl);

            // Run mutation
            Mutation mu =
                    Mutation.newBuilder().setSetJson(ByteString.copyFromUtf8(json)).build();
            txn.mutate(mu);
            txn.commit();

        } finally {
            txn.discard();
        }
        // Query
        String query =
                "query all($a: string){\n" + "all(func: eq(name, $a)) {\n" + "    name\n" + "    friend{name}\n" + "  }\n" + "}";
        Map<String, String> vars = Collections.singletonMap("$a", "Alice");
        Response res = dgraphClient.newTransaction().queryWithVars(query, vars);

        // Deserialize
        People ppl = gson.fromJson(res.getJson().toStringUtf8(), People.class);

        // Print results
        System.out.printf("people found: %d\n", ppl.all.size());
        ppl.all.forEach(person -> {
            System.out.println(person.name);
            System.out.println(person.friend);
        });
    }

    static class Person {
        String name;
        Person friend;

        Person() {}
    }

    static class People {
        List<Person> all;

        People() {}
    }
}
```

I got `JsonSyntaxException`-

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 35 path $.all[0].friend
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
        at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.read(Gson.java:969)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:41)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:82)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:129)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:220)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:887)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:852)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:801)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:773)
        at AppLink.main(AppLink.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 35 path $.all[0].friend
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
        ... 13 more
```

Can anyone help me resolve it?

Comment: show us the result of res.getJson()

Comment: @BasilBattikhi The output of `res.getJson()` is  - `{"all":[{"name":"Alice","friend":[{"name":"Bob"}]},{"name":"Bob"}]}`

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the problem is from `res.getJson()` it tries to convert Array of object to Array of people, unfortunately  gson cannot create direct parsing from JSON Array to Array of Objects you need to pull ***"all"*** and you need to take it's array in order to parse and not the whole object

you need create something like that

```
List<People> people;    
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<People>>() {
                    }.getType();
 people= new Gson().fromJson(new JSONObject(res.getJson().toStringUtf8()).getJSON("all").toString(), listType);
```

Comment: may you give me the json which are you trying to prase?

Comment: I have mentioned that in above comment.

Comment: Thanks! But I got following error - `error: cannot find symbol
        people= new Gson().fromJson(res.getJson().getJSON("all").toStringUtf8(), listType);`

Comment: What is import for `JSONObject`?

Comment: it's library is org.json

Comment: Thanks! Figured that one out. But `.getJSON()` is still not part of its API. Which version should I use?